# grep from MSYS2 not runnable from PowerShell Core function

Tags: powershell, grep, msys2, powershell-core

I'm trying to setup `grep` installed with Git Bash for Windows to be available from [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).

If I have the following in my `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`:

```
Set-alias grep "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe"
```

it works - I can use it with the pipes:

```
❯ echo abc | grep a
abc
```

But I'm missing the `--color=auto` option that on Linux is usually configured in `.bashrc`.

With [some research](https://communary.net/2018/02/16/powershell-6-and-ls/), I found that PowerShell doesn't support aliases with parameters. The workaround is to write a function.

So I did it:

```
Set-alias _grep "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe"
function grep {_grep --color=auto $args}
```

But it doesn't work. The function configured this way doesn't return any output and freezes the shell.

If I manually provide `--color=auto` to grep used in the pipe, it works fine (output is returned and `a` is highlighted):

```
❯ echo abc | _grep --color=auto a
abc
```

`ls --color=auto` used in a function like in the link I provided above also works fine, so I guess that the problem is in my function, which is incompatible with the pipe.

Unfortunately, I don't know PowerShell too well, any ideas?

Comment: A slight caveat re the `$input | ...` approach: all pipeline input is _collected in full, up front_, before it is passed on to the external target program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redirect the piped input to the command you're wrapping.

The most straightforward way is via the [`$input` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input):

```
function grep { $input | _grep --color=auto @args }
```

Comment: Thank you! I definitely need to get along with PowerShell basics